# Rock papers scissor doesn't work

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class stensax extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JPanel p1=new JPanel();
    JPanel p2=new JPanel();
    JPanel p3=new JPanel();
    int x;
    int y;
JButton knapp[] = new JButton [6];

public stensax(){
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,4,6,6));
    p3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Ditt val");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Datorns val");
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Resultat");
    label3.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label3.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++){
        knapp[i] = new JButton();
       /* knapp[i].addActionListener(this); */
        knapp[i].setFont(new Font("Sans Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
        knapp[i].setForeground(Color.blue);
        p2.add(knapp[i]);
    }

    p2.add(label1, 0,0);
    p2.add(label2, 4,4);

    knapp[0].setLabel("Sten");
    knapp[1].setLabel("Sax");
    knapp[2].setLabel("Påse");
    knapp[3].setLabel("Sten");
    knapp[4].setLabel("Sax");
    knapp[5].setLabel("Påse");

    p3.add(label3);

    p3.setVisible(true);
    p2.setVisible(true);
    p1.setVisible(true);
    setVisible(true);


    add(p1);
    p1.add(p2,"North");
    p1.add(p3,"South");
    pack(); 
}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 

        if(e.getSource()==knapp[0]) {
            x=1;    
            logic();
        }

        if(e.getSource()==knapp[1]) {
            x=2;
            logic();
        }

        if(e.getSource()==knapp[2]) {
            x=3;
            logic();
        }


    }

    public void logic(){
         int y = (int)(Math.random() * ((3 - 1) + 1)) + 1;

        if( y == x){
            JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Det blev oavgjort!");
            label3.setText("ok");
            p3.add(label3);
        }

        else if( x == 1 && y == 2){
            JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Du vann!");
            label3.setText("ok");
            p3.add(label3);
        }

        else if( x == 1 && y == 3){
            JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Du förlorade!");
            label3.setText("ok");
            p3.add(label3);
        }

        else if( x == 2 && y == 1){
            JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Du förlorade!");
            label3.setText("ok");
            p3.add(label3);
        }

            if( x == 2 && y == 3){
            JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Du vann!");
            label3.setText("ok");
            p3.add(label3);
        }

        else if( x == 3 && y == 1){
            JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Du vann!");
            label3.setText("ok");
            p3.add(label3);
        }

        else if( x == 3 && y == 2){
            JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Du förlorade!");
            label3.setText("ok");
            p3.add(label3);
        }

    }


public static void main (String[] args){
    stensax fc = new stensax ();
}


}
```

So I'm trying to make a rock paper scissors game for a school project, and this doesn't seem to work. Nothing happens when i press the buttons. It's suposed to change the label dependíng on the outcome of the game. Not really sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm a beginner so sorry if it's something obvious. Thanks in advance!

Comment: spoiler: `((3 - 1) + 1)` will always be `3`.. (haven't read all yet, that just jumped to my eyes)

Comment: Your buttons don't have an actionlistener attached. You commented it out.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this line `/* knapp[i].addActionListener(this); */` to receive action events.

Comment: That is a stupid mistake.. it seems to be able to print it out now, but it doesn't replace "resultat" but it show up in to the left of p3.